# Is it possible to influence the default Access Modifier for user controls?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We have the following situation:

- For our framework we use a lot of user controls (`cCheckBox` instead of `CheckBox`, `cTextBox` instead of `TextBox` etc.)
- We are using a lot of inheritance in our forms.

By default when using drag & drop in the forms designer any instances of e.g. `cCheckBox` will be created with Access Modifier "private" in the designer file. We then have to change this to "protected" afterwards. Is there any way to default this to "protected"? So instead of creating

```
private cCheckBox cCheckBox1;
```

it should create

```
protected cCheckBox cCheckBox1;
```

I found the `ToolboxItem` and `ToolboxBitmap` attributes, which allow me to control the visibility of the control within the Toolbox but I couldn't find anything that allows me to modify the default access modifier.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit 2016-01-04: After some further search I found this (quite old) question: [[Change default access modifier for controls created in UI designer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192871/change-default-access-modifier-for-controls-created-in-ui-designer) There it says it is not possible. I'm wondering if anything has changed though?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? why protected?

Comment: They want to be able to access the child controls from sub-classes, which requires them to be `protected` rather than `private`

Comment: Exactly. In our organisation the international RnD department will develop the base form for our core product and the consulting departments create customer specific derived forms. To not be restricted in how the consulting department adapts the forms to the customers requirements all controls in the forms have to be protected.

Comment: Although I understand the desire for open-ended customizability, I think you are treading a dangerous path here. If these controls can be modified willy-nilly by subclasses, then their behavior cannot be controlled by the base class and the state of the base class could become inconsistent. You might want to consider breaking up your custom control classes and data models enough so that they can be composed into novel creations by the consulting department, rather than fiddled with as derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can change access modifier for each control manually: just select it, press F4 and find `Modifiers` row in the `Properties` window. Access modifier is set to `private` by default for reasons, for example it is for better incapsulation, I guess.

Comment: I believe the question is about a way to set the **default** access modifier so that new controls are created as protected automatically.

Comment: @BradleyUffner, probably it is not possible to change the default behaviour. I'll remove the answer if it is inappropriate for OP.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be deleted, it might be useful for others.

Comment: Yes it is quite easy to change this manually either through the properties or by editing the Designer.cs file. Unfortunately this is something that is easily forgotten (especially with the amount of developers working at our company) and we are looking for a way to control this directly in visual studio

Comment: @JonasFeigl I think if you select multiple controls at one time, you can change their access modifier in one step in the properties panel.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this. Controls added through the toolbox will always be created as private first. The only way to handle this is to manually change it afterwards.